# Extjs 4.2: Get multiple selected cell and get values

Tags: extjs, grid, selection

I currently have this code for my method:

```
createPlaylist:function(record){
    var scope = this;
    var vo = record;
    var sel = scope.getShowImages().getSelectionModel().getSelection();

    var filename = sel[0].data.filename;
    console.log(filename);
}
```

All I get is the value of the first cell selected, but since my seltype of my grid is checkboxmodel, I want to get all the values of the selected cells.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you are using a `checkcolumn`. in your handler, you can try the following:

```
var r = grid.store.getRange();
var selected = [];

for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    if (r[i] != null) {
        if (r[i].data.checkcolumn_dataIndex) { //checks if row is selected
            selected.push(r[i].data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I'm not using checkcolumn. I'm not even familiar with that.